# Retrieve data from _ga cookie

Tags: javascript, php, google-analytics

With the old version of Google analytics it was possible to access to access to origin data of a user looking in the __utmz cookie. Is it possible to do the same from the new _ga cookie? I'd like to retrieve the folloging data:

- source
- medium
- term
- content
- campaign
- gclid

I'd like to do it in php from my backend, so I can store them to my database

Comment: If you're using both ga.js and analytics.js, the _utm parameters are available in analytic.js tracking code. However if the site just contains analytics.js, all of these params are on the server-side and thus unattainable from client-side. You might be able to write some custom code to grab the params out of the url...

Answer (score 1):

No. The analytics.js cookie has only the client id. You can use the [get method](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/method-reference#get)  to retrieve campaign information, but this will only work on the landing page - if you want the info to persist in a user session you'd have to set you own cookie with that information.

Comment: why does this work only in the landing page? could I save their data in my database using an ajax call?

Comment: Because the data is not stored client side (with ga.js this is what the cookie did). analytics.js processes all the data on the server and attributes the source for a session/visitor by looking at the source of the landing page for that visitor. It does not transmit any data back to the client.